# React Router + GH Pages, refresh breaking app

Tags: react-router, github-pages

This isn't happening on my local server,
but when I push my create-react-app to gh-pages and try to reload anything besides the home page,  or navigate directly to a routed page, the page breaks and the URL repeatedly grows looking like this...
`https://hellocentral.live/about/?p=/&q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/~and~q=p=/....`

Here is my file with my routes...

```
import React from "react";
import "./SiteContainer.scss";
import HeaderContainer from "../HeaderContainer/HeaderContainer";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "../About/About";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import Music from "../Music/Music";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import Merch from "../Merch/Merch";
import Pics from "../Pics/Pics";
import Contact from "../Contact/Contact";

export const SiteContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="site-container">
      <HeaderContainer />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/merch" component={Merch} />
        <Route path="/music" component={Music} />
        <Route path="/pics" component={Pics} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SiteContainer;
```

here is my repo
https://github.com/monstaro/hc3/tree/master/src

The site is https://www.hellocentral.live

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `Switch` component in a `Router` component. To do this, you need to import it from the `react-router-dom` package:

```
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
...
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
    ...
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I gave `HashRouter` as example because GH Pages does not support the other router, `BrowserRouter`. Probably, `MemoryRouter` or `StaticRouter` do work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since your domain is https://www.hellocentral.live, you need to set `segmentCount` to `0` [here](https://github.com/monstaro/hc3/blob/3b57ebb25ff6b7f29bfba0ca5410167cae6a0a69/public/404.html#L26).

Guess you're using an older version of [rafgraph/spa-github-pages](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) cited in a blog or something. I would recommend updating `index.html` with [the latest version of the script](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L36-L57) and `404.html` with [this](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/404.html#L6-L36) script.

From the [docs](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages#usage-instructions),

> Note that if you are setting up a Project Pages site and not using a custom domain (i.e. your site's address is username.github.io/repo-name), then you need to set `pathSegmentsToKeep` to 1 in the 404.html file in order to keep /repo-name in the path after the redirect.